# Cannot delete a link (Windows 7)

Tags: file, windows-7-x64, ownership, lnk

I have a file here on an NTFS which is not owned by me. It's a .LNK file and points to a file that does no longer exist. Right clicking on the file and opening the security tab doesn't work since the actual file doesn't exist any more. I tried with the so called "Take Ownership" registry hack which is available as a download from various sites. But at the moment I have even the problem of getting this "take Ownership" tool working under Windows 7. It simply doesn't show up in the explorer popup menu as it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to delete my post but now I decided to share what I did. First I created a physical file in the location where the .LNK  was pointing to.

This allowed me to right click and select the security tab. Don't ask me what I actually did now. Somehow I managed to enable read/write/delete for Everone and finally I was able to delete the file.

The Explorer pop up menu item "Take Ownership" doesn't show on every file or folder when you hat the registry hack installed. It didn't show on this orphaned link nor did it when the physical file it was pointing to had been established (faked). That must be a peculiarity of "Take Ownership" by itself.